# DocuSign Salesforce Apex DocuSignAPI

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

I am coding using Salesforce Apex and DocuSign API.
Here a part of my code :

```
DocuSignAPI.Tab tab100 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab() ;                        
tab100.Type_x = 'Custom' ;     
tab100.RecipientID = 1 ;                           
tab100.DocumentID = 1 ;                           
tab100.PageNumber = 1 ;                           
tab100.XPosition = 40 ;                           
tab100.YPosition = 40 ;
```

Unfortunately, I try to use other field name like "Font, FontSize" but it is not recognized : 
I got this message "Variable does not exist : Font".

Can someone helps me ?

Answer (score 0):

@Jeanson - what are you trying to build? And are you using a library? The tab type must be Text to use Font

Comment: First of all sorry for my english because I am from France. <br/> 
I am trying to send a filled document with DocuSign. I want to fill the document through DocuSign with APEX code. <br/> 

I don't know if it is what you call library but I'm using <br/>
    DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoap dsApiSend = new DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoap();

I've tried to put  <br/>
    tab100.Type_x = 'Text' ; as you suggested but I got the same error "Varible does not exist: FontSize"
    tab100.FontSize =  'Size10' ;

Is there a way to correct that ?  <br/>
Jeanson

Comment: In fact, I am using wwwDocusignNetApi30.APIServiceSoap dsApiSend = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.APIServiceSoap();  but it is the same problem even worst because It doesn't allow tab.Type_x = 'Text'

Comment: How you have created APEX classes, have you used DS WSDL -  https://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/Schema/dsapi.wsdl?, please check [Using DocuSign WSDL in SF](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Introduction+Changes/Using%20DocuSign%20WSDLs%20in%20the%20Salesforce%20Environment.htm)